# how to slide container back in a list view flutter. I am able to achieve slide transition. But, I want to slide back to position with animation

Tags: flutter

```
                       onTap: () {
                         setState(() {
                           vehicleList![index].isSwipe =
                               !vehicleList![index].isSwipe!;
                         });
                       },
                       child: Container(
                           width: screenWidth! * 0.06,
                           height: screenHeight! * 0.22,
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             color: AppTheme.appColors,
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                               topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                               bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                             ),
                           ),
                           child: Icon(Icons.more_vert_outlined,
                               color: Colors.white)),
                     ),
```

I have swipe widget in a separate stateful widget:

```
 if (vehicleDetails.isSwipe!) {
                return SwipeActionWidget(
                    vehicleDetails, index, mapUtils, onTapAction);
              }
```

I have list widget like this:

```
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final vehicleDetails = vehicleList![index];
              if (vehicleDetails.isSwipe!) {
                return SwipeActionWidget(
                    vehicleDetails, index, mapUtils, onTapAction);
              } else {
                return SlideTransition(
                  position: offset!,
                  child: Container(
                    width: screenWidth! * 0.95,
                    height: screenHeight! * 0.20,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Color(0xFFEBEBF0),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Text('${vehicleDetails.vinNumber}'),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    const Text("World"),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                Container(
                                  height: 1,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                ViewListPanel(vehicleDetails, onNavigateClick,
                                    vehicleDetailsList),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              vehicleList![index].isSwipe =
                                  !vehicleList![index].isSwipe!;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                              width: screenWidth! * 0.06,
                              height: screenHeight! * 0.22,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: AppTheme.appColors,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Icon(Icons.more_vert_outlined,
                                  color: Colors.white)),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
```

I am able to see slide transition form swipe widget which is in a separate stateful widget, but when I click on it animation is not showing like example : [image: before animation][image: after animation]previous widget should show with animation

how to slide container back in a list view flutter. I am able to achieve slide transition. But, I want to slide back to position with animation